# How to gain access to each menu item in wordpress?

Tags: menus

I have some menu items in a menu at location "main-menu".
By using `wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'main-menu' ) );` , i get all the 13 items in a div.

Now i just need to show 10 menu items in present div and the remanining in other div (say id="new") just adjacent to it. Again if the div with id "new" has 10 menu-items in it, again a new div will be created and the remaining items are shown in it.

So is there a way to access the array that contains these menu-items?
Please help.

Comment: What should happen with child menu items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides a custom walker, you could also use a filter, such as `wp_nav_menu_args` or `wp_nav_menu_objects` as described [in the codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu)

Answer (score 2):

I belive you can extend Walker_Nav_Menu class to use it for your proposes. In this example important a **custom_menu_walker** element which is your custom walker class.

```
wp_nav_menu( array(
 'container' =>false,
 'menu_class' => 'nav',
 'echo' => true,
 'before' => '',
 'after' => '',
 'link_before' => '',
 'link_after' => '',
 'depth' => 0,
 'walker' => new custom_menu_walker())
 );
```

custom_menu_walker

```
class custom_menu_walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu
{
      function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth, $args)
      {
           global $wp_query;

           $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '';

           $class_names = $value = '';

           $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;

           $class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item ) );
           $class_names = ' class="'. esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"';

           $output .= $indent . '<li id="menu-item-'. $item->ID . '"' . $value . $class_names .'>';

           $attributes  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? ' title="'  . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) .'"' : '';
           $attributes .= ! empty( $item->target )     ? ' target="' . esc_attr( $item->target     ) .'"' : '';
           $attributes .= ! empty( $item->xfn )        ? ' rel="'    . esc_attr( $item->xfn        ) .'"' : '';
           $attributes .= ! empty( $item->url )        ? ' href="'   . esc_attr( $item->url        ) .'"' : '';

           $prepend = '<strong>';
           $append = '</strong>';
           $description  = ! empty( $item->description ) ? '<span>'.esc_attr( $item->description ).'</span>' : '';

           if($depth != 0)
           {
                     $description = $append = $prepend = "";
           }

            $item_output = $args->before;
            $item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .'>';
            $item_output .= $args->link_before .$prepend.apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ).$append;
            $item_output .= $description.$args->link_after;
            $item_output .= '</a>';
            $item_output .= $args->after;

            $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
            }
}
```

this isn't an code for your question, just a small example
You can read a more about custom walkers at [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu) and here on wpse ([1](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/82563/add-items-to-a-menu-dynamically/82567#82567),[2](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14037/menu-items-description-custom-walker-for-wp-nav-menu))

Comment: Thanks a lot Oleg... I was not quite sure about walker classes. Your code seems to be easy to understand... Thanks once again